# Why does this Broadcast Receiver work in Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, manifest

I am a Beginner in programming in Android and now I am sitting in front of this problem: I would code a Broadcast Receiver, which gets fired whenever the Phone gets charged or "discharged". So, registered the Receiver in the Manifest.xml:

```
<receiver
   android:name=".Starter"
   android:enabled="true"
   android:exported="true">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In the Class of the Broadcast Receiver, I wrote a Toast into the onReceive()-Method, which should be performed, when the Receiver would work:

```
>     public class Starter extends BroadcastReceiver {
>     
>         @Override
>         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
>             Toast.makeText(context,"blablabla",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>         }
>     }
```

I am so thankful for every Help, LG

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question? Are you getting an error? Which one? Could you provide more input to the community? See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

When using a `BroadcastReceiver`, it must be registered with the class that will listen for broadcasts.

This is done using `Context.registerReceiver()` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#registerreceiver)

or

`LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(...).registerReceiver(...)` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager).

1. Create `IntentFilter`s that will listen for the particular broadcast.
2. Register your receiver in `onResume()` in a class that extends `Activity` or `Fragment`.

   ```
   class MainActivity extends Activity 
   {
       Starter myReceiver = new Starter(); // This is your class that extends BroadcastReceiver

       @Override
       public void onResume()
       {
           super.onResume();

           // Create IntentFilters that will listen for certain actions:
           IntentFilter intentFilterConnected = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED);
           IntentFilter intentFilterDisconnected = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED);

           // Then pass these intents to registerReceiver():
           registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilterConnected);
           registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilterDisconnected);
       }
   }
   ```

Now myReceiver's `onReceive()` will execute when MainActivity receives the broadcasts matching the `IntentFilter`s.

Note: If the class that instantiates `myReceiver` does not extend `Activity` or `Fragment`, then you will need to use `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(...).registerReceiver(...)`.

Comment: It might be safer to simply call the registerReceiver method once since it might only register it with the last intentFilter. So better do `IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED);
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED);
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);`